# SQL Server : count types with totals by date change

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, cumulative-sum

I need to count a value (`M_Id`) at each change of a date (`RS_Date`) and create a column grouped by the `RS_Date` that has an active total from that date.

So the table is:

```
Ep_Id   Oa_Id   M_Id M_StartDate    RS_Date
--------------------------------------------
    1   2001    5   1/1/2014       1/1/2014
    1   2001    9   1/1/2014       1/1/2014
    1   2001    3   1/1/2014       1/1/2014
    1   2001    11  1/1/2014       1/1/2014
    1   2001    2   1/1/2014       1/1/2014
    1   2067    7   1/1/2014       1/5/2014
    1   2067    1   1/1/2014       1/5/2014
    1   3099    12  1/1/2014       3/2/2014
    1   3099    14  2/14/2014      3/2/2014
    1   3099    4   2/14/2014      3/2/2014
```

So my goal is like

```
RS_Date   Active
-----------------
1/1/2014    5
1/5/2014    7
3/2/2014    10
```

If the `M_startDate = RS_Date` I need to count the `M_id` and then for 
each `RS_Date` that is not equal to the start date I need to count the `M_Id` and then add that to the `M_StartDate` count and then count the next `RS_Date` and add that to the last active count.

I can get the basic counts with something like

```
(Case when M_StartDate <= RS_Date
        then [m_Id] end) as Test.
```

But I am stuck as how to get to the result I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Brian

-added in response to comments
I am using Server Ver 10

Comment: What does it mean to "count the `M_id`"?  Do you mean count the *distinct* values of that column?  If so, is that distinctness requirement scoped to each `RS_Date` group, or is it global?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What significance does it have that `M_StartDate` is different for the last two rows of the example data?  These seem to be included in the count for `RS_Date` 3/2/2014; is that as intended?  Should there in fact be separate results for rows having different different `M_StartDate`?

Comment: Using Server Version 10.0.5500

Comment: @JohnBollinger-  Thank you.  Very helpful. The data is sample for Patient Medications that are active. The M_StartDate is the date the Med was ordered.  The RS_Date is the start of care. So yes it is intended.  No the results "how many meds was the patient on at each RS_Date."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using SQL SERVER 2012+ you can use `ROWS` with your the analytic/window functions:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT RS_Date
                    ,COUNT(DISTINCT M_ID) AS CT
              FROM Table1
              GROUP BY RS_Date
              )
SELECT *,SUM(CT) OVER(ORDER BY RS_Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Run_CT
FROM cte
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3b65/20/1)

If stuck using something prior to 2012 you can use:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT RS_Date
                    ,COUNT(DISTINCT M_ID) AS CT
              FROM Table1
              GROUP BY RS_Date
              )
SELECT a.RS_Date
      ,SUM(b.CT)
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.RS_DAte >= b.RS_Date
GROUP BY a.RS_Date
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3b65/20/1)

Comment: Thanks! I used the first query with cte and worked like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need a cumulative sum, easy in SQL Server 2012 using Windowed Aggregate Functions. Based on your description this will return the expected result

```
SELECT p_id, RS_Date,
   SUM(COUNT(*)) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY p_id 
         ORDER BY RS_Date 
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM tab
GROUP BY p_id, RS_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
SELECT
  RS_Date,
  SUM(c) OVER (PARTITION BY M_StartDate ORDER BY RS_Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING)
FROM
  (
    SELECT M_StartDate, RS_Date, COUNT(DISTINCT M_Id) AS c
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY M_StartDate, RS_Date
  ) counts
```

The inline view computes the counts of distinct M_Id values within each (`M_StartDate`, `RS_Date`) group (distinctness enforced only within the group), and the outer query uses the analytic version of `SUM()` to add up the counts within each `M_StartDate`.

Note that this particular query will not exactly reproduce your example results.  It will instead produce:

```
RS_Date   Active
-----------------
1/1/2014    5
1/5/2014    7
3/2/2014    8
3/2/2014    2
```

This is on account of some rows in your example data with `RS_Date` 3/2/2014 having a later `M_StartDate` than others.  If this is not what you want then you need to clarify the question, which currently seems a bit inconsistent.

**Unfortunately**, analytic functions are not available until SQL Server 2012.  In SQL Server 2010, the job is messier.  It could be done like this:

```
WITH gc AS (
  SELECT M_StartDate, RS_Date, COUNT(DISTINCT M_Id) AS c
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY M_StartDate, RS_Date
)
SELECT
  RS_Date,
  (
    SELECT SUM(c)
    FROM gc2
    WHERE gc2.M_StartDate = gc.M_StartDate AND gc2.RS_Date <= gc.RS_Date
  ) AS Active
FROM gc
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SQL 2012 or newer you can use LAG to produce a running total.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I am not using SQL 2012. I have another server available which is 2012.  I would have to copy things over to try this.

Comment: You dont have to copy all of the data over. You can setup the SQL 2008 server as a linked server on the SQL 2012 server.

Comment: Yes...servers are linked.  Stupid first comment by me in my haste.  Thanks.  btw -All these answers are great.